# Optimal packing for a box layout

Tags: algorithm, packaging

I was making a cutout from a piece of cardboard to make a box with legs. You can describe the sizes of each section with a model laid out in a plane as seen here: http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-1504882-cardboard-box-layout.php

Since my design has legs and is not just a box the layout is not as straightforward. The sections do not have to be placed in any order as long as everything works out when it's folded. This got me thinking, is there an algorithm for finding the closest packing of a layout like this? It sounds similar to the bin packing problem but with more constraints. Any ideas?

EDIT: By closest packing I mean produce a layout such that the least amount of material is used.

Comment: Do you know what the final, folded up box should look like? If so, this sounds more like Polyhedra Unfolding, which is still an open problem in CS. There are lots of approximation algorithms out there, though, that you could find with a quick web search.